# Unable to access elements of Array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, stdvector

I have following situation.

```
class A
{
 public:
    std::vector<double *> getData()
    {
        return test;
    }
    void setData()
    {
        double * data = new double[1];
        data[0] = 1;     
        double data1[] = {1}; 

        test.push_back(data);  // Pushing first element as double *
        test.push_back(data1); // Pushing second element as double[]
    }

    private:
    std::vector<double*> test;
};

class B
{
public :
    void displaySum(A *a)
    {
        std::vector<double *> data = a->getData();

        double sum = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        {
            printf("Data at %d : %f \n", i, data[i][0]); // Getting 0 for second element
            sum = sum + data[i][0];
        }
        printf("Sum is : %f \n", sum);
    }
};

int main()
{
   A *a = new A();
   a->setData();

    B *b = new B();
    b->displaySum(a);

    return 0;
}
```

In class A in have member variable std::vector test and i am filling vector with double* and double[] but in output I was getting 0 value for second element. but as in class A setData method a have added double[] = {1}. so in output i should get 1 at second element. Please help . Am i doing something wrong. If please explain me.
Thank you!

```
OUTPUT ::
Data at 0 : 1.000000 // First Element
Data at 1 : 0.000000 // Second Element ->should be 1
Sum is : 1.000000    // Sum should be 2
```

Comment: `data1` goes out of scope and the pointer becomes dangling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you push `data1`, you're actually pushing a pointer to the first element of `data1` (there's an implicit conversion at that point).

Since `data1` is local to the function, that pointer becomes invalid as soon as `setData` returns.

You need to use dynamic allocation for that as well, or store `vector`s in your `vector`.

Comment: you mean i have to use std::vector<std::vector<double>> ?

Comment: @D'JayPatil I mean that you can. It's easier than fiddling with manual memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

`double data1[] = {1};` is local to `setData()`, getting destroyed after `setData` exits and the content inside vector becomes dangling.

Use :

```
double *data1 = new double (1.0);
```

again in `setData()` to see a `2`

Comment: If i use new (dynamic allocation) is there any memory leakage in this program if yes, how i can avoid that ?

Comment: @D'JayPatil Ouhh yes, forgot to mention, you should free the memory too, this you could do in destructor

Answer (score 1):

From the code what I interpreted is that the code should be able to add array as as well as individual double data and hence maybe instead of using `vector<double *>`, you can use `vector <double>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A
{
 public:
    std::vector<double> getData()
    {
        return test;
    }
    void setData()
    {
        double data = 1.00; 
        double data1[] = {1.00}; 

        test.push_back(data);  // Pushing first element as double

        // Pushing second element as double[]
        for(int i = 0; i < 1 /* Provide array size here */; i ++)
        {
            test.push_back(data1[i]); 
        }
    }

    private:
    std::vector<double> test;
};

class B
{
public :
    void displaySum(A *a)
    {
        std::vector<double> data = a->getData();

        double sum = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        {
            printf("Data at %d : %f \n", i, data[i]); // Getting 0 for second element
            sum = sum + data[i];
        }
        printf("Sum is : %f \n", sum);
    }
};

int main()
{
   A *a = new A();
   a->setData();

    B *b = new B();
    b->displaySum(a);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

- Data at 0 : 1.000000
- Data at 1 : 1.000000
- Sum is : 2.000000

**[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/3kkS1q)**

Comment: i want to add array not array element i used only one element for example i my code i am using 100 elements in array

Comment: As in my code I am adding individual array element which technically does mean to add entire array. Would you please let me know if I am wrong here?

Comment: suppose if i have 10 arrays with 100 size as per your suggestion if i add all elements in vector then vectors size will be 10*100. and if i add array then its size will be 10 this is what i think !

Comment: @D'JayPatil This is how I would do it too. note that the vector can only store one type, so you could do it as you did, and store pointers (why would you? you invalidate all the implicit memory management done by `vector`) in which case you need to ensure that you do all the memory management yourself. Or you can do it this way, which is the smarter way of doing it, unless what you really need is a `vector<vector<T>>`

Comment: @D'JayPatil either way, you will end up with the same number of elements, they are just stored in a different way.  A `vector<vector<T>>` would allow you to have a vector storing 10 vectors of size 100 if that is the behaviour you wish for.

Comment: @Baldrickk in code we are returning vector does it make copy of vector ? if it is creating copy then memory leak will be possible

Comment: you can't leak unless you put pointers to dynamically allocated data into the vector (where the pointer is disposed off when the vector eventually goes out of scope, but the data isn't). The vector class handles all the memory management to _prevent_ you from being able to leak under 'normal' use. Naively, you create a new vector via `std::copy` and dispose of the original when you return a vector (and this new vector points at the original data) but this can be optimised out by the compiler. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)

Answer (score 0):

Second element in vector is garbage value while invoking b->displaySum(a) as second element is referring a local variable